# How to migrate a microservice that uses RESTFul to Spring Webflux reactive

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, spring-webflux

Let's say I have a micro service with spring boot, with a PersonsRestController input like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/world/{countryId}/persons", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<PersonSaverItem> getPublishPersonsByCountry(@PathVariable("countryId") Integer countryId,
                                                                                                @RequestParam(value = "state", required = false) PublishItemState state,
                                                                                                @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = "50", required = false) int limit,
                                                                                                @RequestParam(value = "offset", defaultValue = "0", required = false) int offset) {

    PersonSaverList personSaverList = this.personSaverService.getPublishItemListBy(countryId, state, limit, offset);

    return personSaverList.getpersonSaverList();

}
```

The implementation of personSaverService.getPublishItemListBy (...) looks something like this:

```
@Override
public PersonSaverList getPublishItemListBy(Integer countryId, PublishItemState state, int limit, int offset) {

    try {

        return this.personSaverRepository.getPublishItemsBycountryId(countryId, state, limit, offset);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      ...
    }
}
```

And finally the repository through Spring Jdbc makes a query to a database, Oracle db in this case.

How can I migrate this logic to Spring WebFlux?

I have tried changing only the returned list to a Flux in the controller:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/world/{countryId}/persons", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public Flux<PersonSaverItem> getPublishPersonsByCountry(@PathVariable("countryId") Integer 
      countryId,
  @RequestParam(value = "state", required = false) PublishItemState state,
  @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = "50", required = false) int limit,
  @RequestParam(value = "offset", defaultValue = "0", required = false) int offset) {

       PersonSaverList personSaverList = this.personSaverService.getPublishItemListBy(countryId, state, limit, offset);

       return Flux.fromIterable(personSaverList.getpersonSaverList());
  }
```

but tried JMeter simulating multiple concurrent users (threads) and not seeing any improvement.
I guess more needs to be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using a blocking technology, JDBC, and wrap that in reactive. That won't get you all the benefits. Also when using this with Spring MVC (as you are) you will only get the async part not the other benefits. Finallly there probably isn't any performance benefit (unless things happen in parallel now) but rather it will use less resources, thus allowing for more scaling-up on a single node.

Answer (score 3):

You will only get a real benefit from using a reactive stack if your complete application is reactive. In your case, the problem is the database, which does not support reactive programming and thus is still blocking.

There is a workaround for this ([Spring Data R2DBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc)) that you will need to use so that you can fully benefit from using Spring WebFlux.